# How to determine which variable is closer to 21?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner trying to create the game 21. I searched for similar info, but was unable or missed information pertaining to my problem. I want to be able to determine which score is closer to 21 if both scores are above and or below 21. For instance, if the user says 'n' when asked if they want to roll again and the score is 18 him and 13 the computer, the user should win.

Comment: Do you know about the abs() function?  It always gives you they positive version of an integer value.  So if you do "abs(21 - n):" it will tell you how var 'n' is away from '21' in positive units.  Does that help?

Comment: I think so! I just wrote out a plan of attack and I think this will fix my issue :) Thank you, Steve!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the abs(number) function to solve this:

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))
key = lambda num: abs(21-num)
print("{} is closer than {} to 21".format(min(num1, num2, key=key), max(num1, num2, key=key)))
```

Comment: That's the only answer, how can that be.

Comment: @steve it is always preferable to have an answer present rather than just being answered in the comments!

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." is what stackoverflow says about this. I have no opinion on this so I'll just follow the rules.